# Generating random variable efficiently by groups in data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a following sample data, and I am trying to create random numbers by large number of groups, but it is taking too much time. I wonder whether there is an efficient way for this:

```
library(data.table)
d <- mtcars
n <- 10000
k1<-rbindlist(replicate(n, d, simplify = FALSE))
k1[,factor_var:=rep(seq(1,80000),4)] #sample data
#generating random number
k1[,rand:=runif(nrow(k1),0,1),factor_var]
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do as you are trying to assign 320000 values to 4 rows per each group. Why can't you just run `runif(nrow(k1))` only once?

Comment: @David: I couldn't exactly replicate my original dataset. Think of data as 320000 individual observations (not necessarily the same)  with 80000 households (on average each household has 4 individuals).

Comment: Ok, and what are you trying to do then?

Comment: Generating random number by each group. I don't think this will be the same as just running `runif(nrow(k1))` only once.

Comment: Why do you think it won't be the same?

Comment: @David: I would love to show you why is that, but I still couldn't get my actual output. It is still running.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to show an example that demands a `by`, I think.

Comment: Sure @Frank. I will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this command.

```
k1[, rand:=runif(.N, 0, 1), factor_var]
```

Using nrow is slow in the sense that R computes the number of rows each time. You should either use .N or compute nrow beforehand, like this

```
nr <- nrow(k1)
k1[, rand:=runif(nr, 0, 1), factor_var]
```

Comment: Yes, I think we already established in comments that OP has a bit more complicated situation. At least they claim so.

Comment: I think that the only problem was with nrow inside the table

Comment: Changed `brow` to `nrow`.  I guess you meant nrow

Comment: @Michele: Yes, that is preety fast. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `k1[, rand:=runif(nr, 0, 1), factor_var]` will still be very slow. As per `k1[, rand:=runif(.N, 0, 1), factor_var]` it is pretty much the same as `k1[, rand:=runif(.N)]` but slower.

Comment: It's not just about speed, though. As the warnings say, the object `runif(nr, 0, 1)` is too large to be assigned to the subset of four rows for each `factor_var`.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to compute the number of rows for each chunk, store them, and re-use inside the data table operation. Or just to use the pre-built .N

Comment: I am just confused. Why do you guys think `rand1` and `rand2` will be the same (with the same seed) in. `k1[,rand1:=runif(.N,0,1),factor_var]`
`k1[,rand2:=runif(.N,0,1)]`

Comment: They won't be the same just because different random seeds. But they both will be perfectly random as per your needs.

Comment: I am using the same seed but getting different random numbers (for rand1 and rand2).

Comment: Maybe if you had used `rep(seq(1,80000),each=4)` you would see them the same. The point is that the two vars are generated in the same way. The conditional distribution of Uniform(0,1) given a `factor_var` is the same as the unconditional distribution of Uniform(0,1).

Comment: @Frank: I got your point. I guess its time to refresh these conditional distributions stuff.

Comment: You should try using `set.seed` when comparing results generated by a random seed.